# Add own hook to stash

Tags: bitbucket-server

I am try to develop my own stash hook. Is there any tip, How I can add my own hook to the stash?

I have found only function to load it from marketplace, but I want to add it from my computer, is there any possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Stash admin, you can deploy your add-on with the Stash UI:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does it help? :)

Comment: It makes story a little bit clear, thanks =) But I am not a admin. I guess I have to find him anyway)